# rotation origin of composed texture regions?

Tags: java, libgdx, box2d

I am looking for a  mathematical solution for the "tank" problem:
I have a tank that is composed of the tank body and the cannon:

tank:
5.795 meters width (87 px @ 720p-Resolution = 15 px/mtr)
3.8 meters height (57 px @ 720p-Resolution = 15 px/mtr)

cannon:
6.8 meters width (102 px @ 720p-Resolution = 15 px/mtr)
2.063 meters height (31 px @ 720p-Resolution = 15 px/mtr)...(box2d fixture is only 0.4f height)

Each is a separate object with a box2d body. The tank has a rotation and the cannon has a separate rotation, too. Both box2d bodies are bound together with a joint:

```
RevoluteJointDef jointDef = new RevoluteJointDef();
jointDef.bodyA = getBody();             // the tank-body
jointDef.bodyB = cannon.getBody();
jointDef.localAnchorB.x = -getWidth() / 3.9f;       // not sure what i am doing here !?
joint = (RevoluteJoint) map.box2dworld.createJoint(jointDef);
```

I am drawing two texture regions with their rotation on top of each other for the tank body and the tank cannon. But the origin of the cannon is NOT the center of that texture region. Let's say that the origin of the tank is the center of the tank body texture region. And the rotation origin of the tank cannon should be exactly at the origin of the tank body. But this origin of the cannon is shifted to one side (see screenshot)

## RENDERING

```
batch.draw(tankTextureRegion, 
tank.getPosition().x - tank.getWidth() * 0.5f, 
tank.getPosition().y - tank.getHeight() * 0.5f,
tank.getWidth() * 0.5f, tank.getHeight() * 0.5f,
tank.getWidth(), tank.getHeight(), 1, 1, 
tank.getAngleInDegress());

batch.draw(cannonTextureRegion, 
tank.getPosition().x - tank.getWidth() * 0.5f + 1f,     // +1f is sort of a tweaking / Workaround
tank.getPosition().y - tank.getHeight() * 0.5f + 1f,    // +1f is sort of a tweaking / Workaround
2.0f, 1.0f, 6.8f, 2.063f, 1, 1,             // 2.0f, 1.0f .... not quite sure here!
tank.cannon.getOwnAngle() * MathUtils.radiansToDegrees);
```

=> the problem is, that the cannon is still shifting a bit around when i rotate cannon or tank.
so i guess there are some values about the origin of the cannon incorrect.

any help is very appreciated !!

bye
phil

p.s.: i googled this a lot but didnt find a solution although there are some similar topcis

https://i.stack.imgur.com/UJHjx.jpg

Comment: i tried to take as the cannon origin the (tank.width / 2) - offset.x of the cannon. now it seems to work perfectly

Comment: If you have a solution, please post it and accept it. Saying _SOLVED_ in the title is pointless.

Comment: or unask your question, since the solution was literally just picking an origin and the question thus probably posted prematurely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i had to take as the cannon origin the (tank.width / 2) - offset.x of the cannon. now it seems to work perfectly.

```
        batch.draw(cannonTextureRegion, 
                tank.getPosition().x - tank.getWidth() * 0.5f + 1f, 
                tank.getPosition().y - tank.getHeight() * 0.5f + 0.8667f,
                tank.getWidth() * 0.5f - 1f,                        // origin.x
                tank.getHeight() * 0.5f - 0.8667f,                  // origin.y
                6.8f, 2.06667f, 1, 1,                               // size & scale
                tank.cannon.getOwnAngle() * MathUtils.radiansToDegrees);
```